# Does a True value exist in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I create a list of dictionaries like this:

```
list = []

for i in xrange(4):
    list.append({})
    list[i]['a'] = False
```

Now after a while, I want to (using a single line of code) see if any of the 'a' values are True.

I have tried:

```
anyTrue = True in list             # always returns false
anyTrue = True in list[:]['a']
```

Is there such a convenient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> lst = []
>>>
>>> for i in xrange(4):
...     lst.append({})
...     lst[i]['a'] = False
...
>>> any(d['a'] for d in lst)
False

>>> lst[1]['a'] = True
>>> any(d['a'] for d in lst)
True
```

BTW, don't use the `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function/type [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: I think that should be `d['a']` not `'a' in d`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer after reading your comment.

Comment: Wow this was a very quick answer. With jonrsharpe's correction it works fine, so thanks both of you. I will accept the answer as soon as this page lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
if any(x['a'] for x in list):
    # Do stuff
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> for i in xrange(4):
...     lst.append({})
...     lst[i]['a'] = False
...
>>> any(x['a'] for x in lst)
False
>>> lst[2]['a'] = True  # Set an 'a' value to True
>>> any(x['a'] for x in lst)
True
>>>
```

Also, you should refrain from naming a variable `list`.   Doing so overshadows the built-in.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I won't name anything `list` in future.